# How to find the most stable facet for a crystal?

Tags: density-functional-theory, crystallography

I am trying to find the most stable facet for a crystal, but since there are many possible choices, like (1 0 0),(1 1 0),(1 1 1),(2 1 0), etc. My questions is:

**I am wondering how should I determine the potential stable facets and then do more precise calculations to verify which one is the most stable facet?**

Comment: Check, for example [surfaxe](https://github.com/SMTG-UCL/surfaxe) which uses `pymatgen`. There's also a great article of checking multiple facets for [metal surfaces](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201680)

Comment: If you're asking about the theory of facet stability, the stability is determined by the energy E per surface area A, with the lowest E/A being preferred. Once you know E/A for each possible facet, the optimal crystal shape can be worked out using a Wulff construction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wulff_construction

Comment: @PhilHasnip could you expand/convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @Camps I'm not entirely sure whether that's the question though, I think it might be asking how you know which facets are likely candidates *before* doing the simulations.